# Nested Array Check if Exists

Tags: php, variables, foreach, undefined

I have a foreach loop that looks like this:

```
foreach($arr["CREDIT_LIABILITY_CREDITOR"]["ADDRESS"] as $key => $value){...}
```

The ["CREDIT_LIABILITY_CREDITOR"] array always exists but the ["ADDRESS"] array is sometimes missing. When the address array is not present, it is thowing this error:

```
 Undefined index: ADDRESS
```

Is there a way to suppress the warning or make null if the Address array doesn't exist?

Comment: just check the index first before you iterate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrapping it in `if(!empty($arr["CREDIT_LIABILITY_CREDITOR"]["ADDRESS"]) {...}` fixed my problem.

Comment: Alternative: `foreach ($arr['CREDIT_LIABILITY_CREDITOR']['ADDRESS'] ?? [] as $key => $value)`.